# I want to have a css to be applied over another

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a button that is displayed in a lot of pages of my website (With an automated javascript Widget).

I want this CSS :

```
.app.programEditor .col-2 .actions .widget.bt-flat.programs > .bt-flat-icon {
}
```

to be applied, and not this one :

```
.app.programEditor .actions .widget.bt-flat > .bt-flat-icon {
    left: 145px !important;
    top: 19px !important;
```

But instead, what happens, is the two css are applied, and as a result I get the second element that overwrites what I want to do with the first CSS ( A blank css with no rules )

Please I really need your help

Comment: in the first rule you need to revert the top and left properties. An empty rule has no effect

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but please can you show me how to do that in  code ?

Comment: @OssamaBenbouidda I might suggest you need to post the HTML. It's a specificity issue which you can read more about here: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply change it to `position:static` this is just a demo. Otherwise, if you understand concept of Specificity very well, then there was no need for this question.

```js
$('#change').click(function() {
  $('.one').css("position", "static");
  $('.one').text("Position changed to Static")
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.one {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  left: 118px!important;
  top: 30px!important;
  display: block;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">

    Positioned using absolute or relative</div>
</div>
<button id="change">Change CSS</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of your problem is the poorly written rule that uses `!important`. This is an excellent example of why not to use `!important`. If at all possible, try to understand why `!important` was thought to be needed there, and see if you can remove it.

But if you are left fighting against an important rule, your only choice is to fight fire with fire, and toss back an `!important` of your own, in a rule designed to take precedence either because it is more specific (in this case, your override rule has seven classes, to the original rules's six, so it **is** more specific), putting it later in the file if it has the same specificity, or if you have no other choice use the various tricks available to jack up the specificity.

Having said that, overall this CSS seems to be poorly structured, verbose, and inefficient.

```
.app.programEditor .actions .widget.bt-flat > .bt-flat-icon {
```

First, if `.app` is a class applied to your entire application, it is probably not necessary. If `.actions` only occurs within `.app.programEditor`, then the latter is not necessary at all. If `.bt-flat` can only apply to widgets, then instead of `widget.bt-flat` you can just write `.bt-flat`. If `.bt-flat-icon` can only occur within `.bt-flat`, as seems likely, then `.widget.bt-flat` may not be necessary. And so on. In general, instead of writing down every single class in the HTML hierarchy in your CSS rules, try to limit selectors to those necessary to unique select the element you want. In this case, for example,  it is possible your rule could be written as simply as (just an example):

```
.programEditor .actions .widget > .bt-flat-icon {
```

Second, the magic numbers 145 and 19 are a massive code smell. They are probably connected to other magic widths and heights elsewhere in the CSS, and would have to be changed if those change. What do the 145 and 19 mean? Perhaps they are actually a percentage of some underlying dimension. In other words, maybe some element is 160 pixels wide, and we want to place the icon to the upper right. In that case, instead of hard-wiring the 145, you can either use a percentage, or specify a `right` property, or use the `transform` property perhaps, so no matter how the width changes--such as with the introduction of `.col2`--the icon remains in the right place with the original rule.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! It made understand a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

If many rules exist, the first one takes precedence, but if the last one is more specific, it will override the first one. BUT if the first one is less specific AND has `!important` that one will take precedence. :) To make matters more complicated, if both rules has `!important` the most specific rule will take precedence.

So the easy solution here, if you cannot change the already existing rule, just add `!important` to the code you can edit. If that doesn't work, try to get your code processed earlier in the code than the other one.

```
.app.programEditor .col-2 .actions .widget.bt-flat.programs > .bt-flat-icon {
  left: 40px !important;
  top: 40px !important;
}
```

Comment: The override rule does **not** need to come before the other one, since it has higher specificity(seven classes compared to six).

Comment: True, but if an !important rule precedes another more specific !important rule, which one takes precedence? :) I would believe its the one coming first, not the most specific, but I might be wrong on that one, have not tested it.

Comment: Among all important rules, the more specific takes precedence, no matter what order it appears in; given equal specificity, the last rule wins. If there are no applicable important rules, then among all non-important rules, the more specific takes precedence, no matter what order it appears in.

Comment: @torazaburo: Thanks, I updated my explanation, but left the original code suggestion since I still believe that one was right all along. To sum it up, "be specific" :)

Comment: Almost. It should be "If many rules exist, the last one takes precedence, but if an earlier one is more specific, it will override the later ones".